# PHP - create a multidimensional array according to a string's delimiters

Tags: php, recursion, nested

I want to split the following text :

**"some text [aaa[b[c1][c2]d]e][test] more text"**

into a nested array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => aaa[b[c1][c2]d]e
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b[c1][c2]d
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => c1
                    [1] => c2
                )

        )

    [2] => test
)
```

The "recursiveSplit" function found on the php manual works well to display the results.

Here is the function:

```
function recursiveSplit($string, $layer) {
    preg_match_all("#\[(([^\[\]]*|(?R))*)\]#", $string, $matches);
    // iterate thru matches and continue recursive split
    if (count($matches) > 1) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
            if (is_string($matches[1][$i])) {
                if (strlen($matches[1][$i]) > 0) {
                    echo "<pre>Layer ".$layer.":   ".$matches[1][$i]."</pre><br />";
                    recursiveSplit($matches[1][$i], $layer + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

recursiveSplit($string, 0);
```

It displays the following:

```
Layer 0:   aaa[b[c1][c2]d]e

Layer 1:   b[c1][c2]d

Layer 2:   c1

Layer 2:   c2

Layer 0:   test
```

I can't modify the function to get the results into an array or even a simple string. I am completely stuck. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add items to the result array instead of echoing, and also add recursiveSplit call result too, like that:

```
<?php
function recursiveSplit($string, $layer) {
    $result = array();
    preg_match_all("#\[(([^\[\]]*|(?R))*)\]#", $string, $matches);
    // iterate thru matches and continue recursive split
    if (count($matches) > 1) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
            if (is_string($matches[1][$i])) {
                if (strlen($matches[1][$i]) > 0) {
                    $result[] = $matches[1][$i];
                    echo "<pre>Layer ".$layer.":   ".$matches[1][$i]."</pre><br />";
                    $rec = recursiveSplit($matches[1][$i], $layer + 1);
                    if ($rec) {
                        $result[] = $rec;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$string = "some text [aaa[b[c1][c2]d]e][test] more text";
$result = recursiveSplit($string, 0);
print_r($result);
```